# why I can't change Typescript version even though I have downgraded the version

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

so previously, I installed Typecript on my new macbook by running this command

```
sudo npm install typescript -g
```

and I got Typescript version 4.7.4. and then I want to deploy the function using this command

```
firebase deploy
```

unfortunately, there is a warning like this

> WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is
> not officially supported by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree.
>
> You may find that it works just fine, or you may not.
>
> SUPPORTED TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=3.3.1 <4.1.0
>
> YOUR TYPESCRIPT VERSION: 4.7.4
>
> Please only submit bug reports when using the officially supported
> version.

and then I downgrade to version 4.0.7, but unfortunately that warning still exist, it seems my app is still on v4.7.4 (cached ? ) I am sure I have changed the typescript version on package.json and I also check via terminal like the image below

[image]

[image]

but why my node app still have version v.4.7.4 ? not v.4.0.7 ? what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You installed typescript as globally on your system but you changed just in your package.json.

First you should type this `npm uninstall -g typescript`.

Then `npm install -g typescript@your version`.

After that you can uninstall your local tsc on your project.

Answer (score 0):

fiuhhh....after 2 days, I finally find the solution

I have to change the `dependencies` and also the `devDependencies`, especially these dependencies in the `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4" // <-- watch this version
  },
```

the problem is ....it seems to me that these dependencies is tightly coupled. it can easily break if it doesn't match. so my solution is to create new project just to copy and paste those dependencies combination above with the latest version recommended by firebase. watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0) if you are confused how to initialize cloud function project

first, Update your firebase tools to the latest version using this command

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

and change to your directory and init the project

```
cd desktop
mkdir forCopyPasteDependenciesOnly
firebase init
```

select cloud function and typescript. and then you copy those dependencies above and paste it on your problematic project

in my case, I also change the typescript globally using the recommended typescript version from the project `package.json` that you just initialize (4.5.4, not 4.0.7 or 4.7.4 in my case )

```
sudo npm uninstall -g typescript
sudo npm install -g typescript@4.5.4
```

and then, in your problematic project, delete your `node-modules` folder

and delete your `package-lock.json`. and finally run these 2 commands below

```
npm cache clean –force
npm install
```

and when you run `firebase deploy` you may see errors, but luckily it just error from eslint you just update, you can solve it easily.

I hope it helps